# How bind a textfield with combo box values in extjs6?

Tags: javascript, extjs, reference, viewmodel, extjs6

I'm using [extjs-6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0) in my application. I have a [combo box](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox). This combo can have 3 values. If user select `value1` or `value2` , It have to register two `textfield`, But If he select `value3`, He have to register three `textfield`.

I know extjs-6 have a `reference` config and I can use as follow:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Sign Up',

    viewModel: {
        type: 'test'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        boxLabel: 'Is Admin',
        reference: 'isAdmin'
    },{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Admin Key',
        bind: {
            disabled: '{!isAdmin.checked}'
        }
    }]
});
```

**How can I implement this**?
**Note**: These `textfield`s(two of theme for `value1, vlaue1` and three of theme for `value3` are required).

Comment: have you try to bind value on checkbox?
bind : {value: '{checkBoxValue}' }.
then you can get in on the viewModel

Comment: how get `checkBoxValue`?

Comment: you will find it on the viewModel. also you can bind hidden value of the text fields according to formula in the viewModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In my examples I will disable a textfield based on the selected record of the combobox. There are two (or even more) ways to accomplish this.*

1. > You can bind the selected record of the combo and set 'disabled' of
   >   the textfield (or whatever bindable config) using this binded
   >   record.
2. > You can use a formula and based on the selected value of the
   >   combo you return true or false (or another property of the selected
   >   record) to set 'disabled' of the textfield.

### Bind the selected record in the declaration of the view (without using the viewmodel)

To bind the selected record to a property add this to your combo config:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    bind: {
        selection: '{selectedRecord}'
    }
}
```

Now you can use that property to set disabled. Add this to the config of your textfield:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    bind: {
        disabled: '{!selectedRecord.value}'
    }
}
```

Here you can find a working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tec

### Use a formula and return a value (based on the selected record) to bind

To get the selected record of the combo create a formula which is bind to the combo using it's reference config:

```
formulas: {
     disableTextField: {
         bind: {
             bindTo: '{data2.selection}',
             deep: true
         },
         get: function(record) {
             return record ? record.id !== 3 : true;
         }
    }
 }
```

Now bind the return value of 'disableTextField' to the desired property of the textfield:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    reference: 'data2'
}, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    bind: {
        disabled: '{disableTextField}'
    }
}
```

Here you can find a working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/te8